# Find whole part of list item, not subparts, in a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, comparison, string-comparison

I have a dictionary of keys & values (massively truncated for ease of reading):

```
responsePolarities = {'yes':0.95, 'hell yes':0.99, 'no':-0.95, 'hell no':-0.99, 'okay':0.70}
```

I am doing a check to see if any key is in a string passed to my function:

```
for key, value in responsePolarities.items():
    if key in string:
        return value
```

Problem is that if, in the passed string, a word such as "know" is in it, the function sees the 'no' in 'know' and returns a -0.95.

I can't add spaces around the 'no' key because it could be the only response provided.

How can I make the function see 'no' as 'no' but not 'know'?  Am I correct in thinking this is probably going to need to be a RegExp job, or is there something more simple I'm missing?

I thought about splitting my passed string into individual words, but then I couldn't check for multi-word phrases that modify the response polarity (like no vs. hell no)...

Comment: So, you want the key to be "no" or have "no" in it? Is "know no" fine?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Not quite understanding your question.  If I pass the string "I don't know" to the function, the responsePolarity returns as  -0.95 because it matches the 'no' in 'know'.  I don't want that.  I only want it to match 'no' if the word 'no' stands alone and is not simply a coincidental pair of letters in a larger word like know, snow, north, snore, etc.

Comment: So is "know no" fine? Or "hell no" if you prefer.

Comment: @Akaisteph7  No...'know no' is not fine.  If the string being checked was 'no know', it should return a -0.95 for the stand-alone 'no'.  But if the string being checked was 'know yes', it should return a 0.95 for the yes, and not ever see a 'no' in 'know' as being a valid item to check.

Comment: What you are saying seems contradictory. Why don't you just add an example of expected input and output for a couple of cases in your question.

Comment: Examples:  "No way dude, not going to happen" --> -0.95; "Hell yes, I'd love to know how to do that" --> 0.99; "Sorry, that would be a big hell no if they asked me" --> -0.99; "Sure, that would be okay with me" --> 0.70.  "So what fun would that be?" --> 0.00   Eventually I will be doing multiple response checks, so if there were two or more in the passed string, it would return both:  "I don't know if I'm ready to say yes, or even okay, right now, so for now, it'll have to be a no." -->  0.95, 0.70, -0.95.  See last sentence - notice that words 'know' and 'now' do NOT generate an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to match text that contains your keys, but only if the whole word matches. You can do this using the regex word boundary delimiter `\b`. It will match when the word is separated by punctuation, like `:no,` but not other word characters like `know`. Here you loop through some strings and for each find the matching keys in the dictionary:

```
responsePolarities = {'yes':0.95, 'hell yes':0.99, 'no':-0.95, 'hell no':-0.99, 'okay':0.70}

strings = [
    'I know nothing',
    'I now think the answer is no',
    'hell, mayb yes',
    'or hell yes',
    'i thought:yes or maybe--hell yes--'
]

for s in strings:
    for k,v in responsePolarities.items():
        if re.search(rf"\b{k}\b", s):
            print(f"'{s}' matches: {k} : {v}")
```

`'I know nothing'` shouldn't match anything. The matches should look like:

> 'I now think the answer is no' matches: no : -0.95
>   'hell, mayb yes' matches: yes : 0.95
>   'or hell yes' matches: yes : 0.95
>   'or hell yes' matches: hell yes : 0.99
>   'i thought:yes or maybe--hell yes--' matches: yes : 0.95
>   'i thought:yes or maybe--hell yes--' matches: hell yes : 0.99

If you are doing a lot of searches, you might consider precompiling the regexes before the loop.

Comment: Thanks - I was pretty sure RegExp was going to be my only option here.  Thanks, appreciate the confirmation and your efforts here :)